# jQuery effect goes once but I need it to recur

Tags: jquery

I'm using .fadeIn and .fadeOut and can get the effect to happen once, the problem is getting it to happen each time the link is moused over.  I've tried dripping in .deQueue() and .stop() to no avail.  (newb here, so please be patient and thorough in your explanation - much is still over my head)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
p { position:relative; width:400px; height:90px; }
div {
position:fixed;
padding-top:25px;  
top:300px;
left:300px;
display:none;
}
span { display:none; } 
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<a href="#">MouseOver!</a>

<h3><div><span>Sample Text</span></div></h3>

<script>
$("a").mouseover(function () { 
$("div").fadeIn(0, function () { 
$("span").fadeIn(3000);
}); 
return false; 
});  

$("a").mouseout(function () { 
$("h3").fadeOut(3000);
});

</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your selector. You fade in a span but fade out an h3.  Thus the containing h3 will never be faded back in.

You need

```
$("span").fadeIn(3000);
...
$("span").fadeOut(3000);
```

Comment: Is there a quick fix to stop it from pulsing?  The example above doesn't do that but when I drop it in the page I get this undesired effect.

Comment: @Scott there sure is. try this one http://jsfiddle.net/Wna2D/ (it uses the .stop() method)

Comment: it should :( what browser/version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're fading those elements in, but not changing their visible state on `mouseout`. You can use the [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event with a single function to achieve the desired behaviour.

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    $("div").fadeToggle(3000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work for me.  I've tried .hover but am working in firefox and have better luck with keeping the functions separate (.mouseover and .mouseout).  Is there something I can add to my existing code that would fix this?

Comment: @Scott - the event handlers need to be bound on `$(document).ready(`

Comment: You are fading a `div` and a `span` which is a children of `div` itself. When the `div` fades `span` will automatically fade.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are fading div and span both. If you are fading any element then child elements are also faded. Try this

```
$("a").mouseover(function () { 

   $("div").fadeIn(3000); 
   return false; 

}).mouseout(function () { 
   $("div").fadeOut(3000);
});
```

Comment: Wrong, the h3 will fade out, but the div will fade in. h3 is still hidden so element won't show. -1 for wrong answer.

Comment: @Rikido - Thanks, I Corrected it. Now the down vote should go now :)

Answer (score 0):

Well of course it only runs once, you fade in the div and the span, but you fade out the h3. Also your markup makes no sense. Consider this improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/gRAGe/

It consists of jQuery and HTML improvements. Please go over them and consider using this better example.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are fading out the parent element `h3` You cant fade in the others when its hidden. Your `div`, also starts hidden forcing you to display it in order to fade in the span. I would honestly just change your markup to something more simple, or at least remove one layer of hidden elements.

Below will work if you remove `dispay : none` from your div in the css.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fBeV3/1/)**

```
$("a").hover(function(){
        $("span").fadeIn(300);
},function(){
        $("span").fadeOut(300);
});
```

Also its easier to use **[hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)**, because you can then control what happens in one method.